# Countdowntimer Textview

Tags: android, time, textview, countdowntimer, milliseconds

I created this app and now I wanted to use a textview to show the seconds until the other activity starts but I don't know how,I created a txtview inside the countdowntimer but its never shown

```
Event=new String(Edt.getText().toString());
final int time = Integer.parseInt(sec.getText().toString());

Intent myInt = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Receiver.class);

myInt.putExtra("key",Event);
endingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this,2,myInt,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+(time*1000),pendingIntent);

new CountDownTimer(time*1000, 1000) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        txtV.setText("Activity starts"+millisUntilFinished/1000+"seconds"); // here is the txtV which isn't shown 
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

Comment: How about starting a `CountDownTimer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need start your counter by calling [start method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html#start%28%29)

But be carefull, you can only change view from thread, which create this view. One way you can do it is [post runnable on view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29):

```
    CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(time*1000, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            txtV.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                            txtV.setText("Activity starts"+millisUntilFinished/1000+"seconds"); // here is the txtV which isn't shown 
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
    timer.start();
```